# Get currently used OS CPU percentage from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have searched but couldn't find it. Is there a query that will give the the current operation system (windows) used CPU in percentage? Like we all can see in task manager.

Thanks.

Comment: but the memory i am able to get.

Comment: You can do it with CLR

Comment: Here may be something of use to you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176083.aspx

Comment: What do you mean by CLR ?

Comment: @marc_s It seems you're wrong about SQL Server not providing detailed OS runtime data.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1275585-392-1.aspx)

```
    SELECT TOP 1
        record_time,
        SQLProcessUtilization,
        SystemIdle,
        100 - SystemIdle - SQLProcessUtilization AS OtherProcessUtilization
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            record.value('(./Record/@id)[1]', 'int') AS record_id,
            record.value('(./Record/SchedulerMonitorEvent/SystemHealth/SystemIdle)[1]', 'int') AS SystemIdle,
            record.value('(./Record/SchedulerMonitorEvent/SystemHealth/ProcessUtilization)[1]', 'int') AS SQLProcessUtilization,
            record_time
        FROM (
            select 
                dateadd (ms, r.[timestamp] - sys.ms_ticks, getdate()) as record_time,  
                cast(r.record as xml) record  
            from sys.dm_os_ring_buffers r  
            cross join sys.dm_os_sys_info sys  
            where   
                ring_buffer_type='RING_BUFFER_SCHEDULER_MONITOR' 
                AND 
                record LIKE '%<SystemHealth>%'
            ) AS x
        ) AS y
```

Also, please note - as Shanky as pointed out - sys.dm_os_ring_buffers is not supported and future compatibility is not guaranteed. This means that it may change in a future upgrade of SQL Server. For more info see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176083.aspx).

Comment: what is record time ?

Comment: You must also add sys.dm_os_ring_buffer is not supported DMV although safe. The issue with unsupported DMV is MS can change it without giving information , so you must be cautious

Comment: @GiladAdar It looks like the exact time the utilization was recorded.

Comment: It doesn't help me, i need one record that say: 60% used cpu for example

Comment: @GiladAdar just take the top record (SELECT TOP 1 ...). The SQL Process Utilization column is the percentage CPU used by SQL Server.

Comment: It's not in real-time anyway. I fixed my problem using powershell script from sql, thank you.